# Undetermined status for the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits (suid vs nosuid options) on a mounted filesystem?

Tags: mount, automounting

The man page for `mount` indicates:

```
suid    Allow set-user-ID or set-group-ID bits to take effect.

nosuid  Do not allow set-user-ID or set-group-ID bits to take effect.
```

but no indication that one or the other of these options is the default.

At the same time, I cannot find anything about the `suid` or `nosuid` status of my root filesystem:

- If I execute the command `$ mount` I get:

`/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)`.

- I don't see any `suid` or `nosuid` option inside the file `/etc/fstab`.
- In `/proc/mounts` it only indicates:

`/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0`.

- I cannot find anything in the man pages of `mkfs.ext4` or `tune2fs`, or in the file `/etc/mke2fs.conf`.

So my questions are:

- How is the status `suid` or `nosuid` chosen when a filseystem is mounted?
- Where can one find the `suid` or `nosuid` status of a mounted filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`suid` is the default. The explicit `suid` option is only needed for the case where you want to remount a file system or override the options from `/etc/fstab`.

This isn't part of your question, but notice that the `nosuid` option also affects file capabilities -- they will be ignored on filesystems mounted that way.

Comment: Would you have a reference for `suid` being the default? I did not manage to find the information. Is it referenced in some man pages?

Comment: the nosuid option is an artifact of the mount *utility* -- the mount(2) system call only has a `MS_NOSUID` option, there is no `MS_SUID`.

Comment: man page says: `defaults
              Use the default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.`

Comment: And it is documented under the **defaults** meta-option in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) of the mount(8) utility.

Comment: it should've been "the **suid** option is an artifact" in the comment above, sorry.

Comment: @Jasen: Yes, I had seen that, but then I thought that the existence of a 'defaults' option might imply the absence of "silent" default options. But the example case of mosvy now explains it. But indeed, looking back at it now, I could have guessed it was rather implying the existence of default options.

Comment: @mosvy: No problem, I got the idea. Thanks for your answer and the additional insights.